# Web applications don't work in SharePoint 2013 Standard

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, web-application, iis, sharepoint-standard

In my new SP 2013 farm, the first webapp I created worked fine when I created the root site collection and disabled loopback check and gave backconnectionstringnames in the regedit.

I had to delete the web app and then I installed some farm solutions and created a new web app

But now the web apps just deosn't work.

The mysite web app works fine, but any other web application I create just doesnt work. I tried to create one after another. I tried creating one on port 8080 as well, doesn't work.

I have checked the bindings and supplied the host name and IP address there.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

The only screen I see when I run the new sites is "This page can't be displayed"

Comment: did you create the root level site collection in new web app? how you accessing the site..http://servername & port number?

Comment: Yes I've created the root site, I didn't include the port number in the address.

Comment: are you using the fqDN? tryt o aacess it with port number

Comment: Tried FQDN with port, didn't work. I don't know why this is happening now, ive checked the services, ive checked the IIS, ive check regedit. I dont know what I am missing now @waqassarwarmcse

Comment: try with server name and port number

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE servername is my central administration, that works.

Comment: what you mean....if you browse the server name, it bring your central admin?

Comment: Yes, I gave the url of my central admin as the servername

Comment: so only central admin is working?

Comment: central admin and mysites host are the two applications that are working, whatever I create now is not working.

Comment: could you please share their configureation, are you using server name and port number or using the FQDN dns entries for it?

Comment: I'm using fqdn dns entries ....... but ...... the first time I created the web app, I didn't add it as an A record in the DNS, and it still worked. Then I deleted that web app and created new one,,, now the new web app doesn't work. Its not possible for me to add as an A record right now, But  since the last one worked, I am hoping this would work as well without the need of adding it as an A record in DNS

Comment: check my answer if that make sense

Answer (score 1):

there are couple of ways to create Web Application.

Using Server Name and Port number.( with this you cant have multiple web application on same port)

- Create a Web Application, pick the port( http://Server Name:Port number) port should be unique.
- Now create a root level site collection.
- Now browse the site using http://servername:portnumber

Using DNS a record.

- Create a DNS record and point it to the WFE
- Now create the Web application
- use DNS record as Host header

  - port 80( if you want to use it port 80)
  - Now create Root Level Site collection
- Browse the Site using the DNS a record